# Find the limit of the sequence $\{x_n \}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> > Let $\{x_n \}$ be a sequence defined by $x_n = \left(1 - \frac {1} {n^2} \right)^{\binom {n} {2}},\ n \geq 1$. Find the limit of the sequence $\{x_n \}$.

I find difficulty in doing this. Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You say you find it difficult. What have you tried so far, and where does the difficulty lie there? (Your question posits you thought about it. What are your thoughts and attempts?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \left( \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^{n^2} \right)^{\frac{n-1}{2n}} \to (e^{-1})^{\frac{1}{2}} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}} $$
This is true because, if you take the logarithm, you have
$$ \log(x_n) = \binom{n}{2} \cdot \log(1- \frac{1}{n^2}) = \frac{n-1}{2n} \cdot \left( n^2 \cdot |log(1-\frac{1}{n^2}) \right)$$
The first part goes to $\frac{1}{2}$ and the second one goes to $-1$.

Thus their product goes to $-\frac{1}{2}$, hence the result.

Comment: Without more details, I don't see how that's a proof. You're doing non-trivial composition of limits here, which (while, of course, correct in this case) needs to be rigorously justified. Otherwise similar-looking "derivations" can lead to absurdities.

Comment: They are clearly ok, since it isn't an indetermined form! ($e^{-1} \neq 1$ and $\frac{1}{2} \neq 0$)

Comment: Here they are OK. But the OP (who gave no indication of their mathematical knowledge whatsoever) may not see that, may not know how prove it, may not know how to distinguish it from a case where this is **not** OK.

Comment: I will add more details then!

Comment: Thank you. ${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

$a_n= (1-1/n^2)^{n^2}$; $b_n = (1-1/n^2)^n;$

$x_n = (a_n/b_n)^{1/2}$;

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n = e^{-1}$.

(subsequence of $(1-1/n)^{1/n}$).

$b_n = [(1-1/n^2)^{n^2}]^{1/n}=$

$\exp ((1/n)\log ((1-1/n^2)^{n^2})$.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n =e^0=1$.

Combining:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n =$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_n/b_n)^{1/2}= $

$[\frac{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n}{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_n}]^{1/2}= e^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x_n = \left(1 - \frac {1} {n^2} \right)^{\binom {n} {2}}\implies \log(x_n)={\binom {n} {2}}\log\left(1 - \frac {1} {n^2} \right)\sim -\frac {\frac{1}{2} (n-1) n} {n^2}\sim - \frac{1}{2}$$